# ServiceStack event for client disconnect

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I'm experimenting with ServiceStack's Server Events feature and want to make a sort of "online users" test app. The idea is I want to update each user that connects to a channel "Users" whenever a new user joins or leaves. The problem is I cannot find a way to detect when a subscription/user leaves/disconnects.

Answer (score 0):

The `ServerEventsClient.OnCommand` callback is fired when a User **Joins**, **Leaves** or **Updates** their ServerEvent subscription.

You can also fetch a list of all active subscribers from a channel at anytime with:

```
var sseClient = new ServerEventsClient(...);

var response = sseClient.ServiceClient.Get(new GetEventSubscribers { 
    Channels = sseClient.Channels
});
```

Which will return a List of untyped `Dictionary<string,string>` containing the subscribers public info.

I've also just added a Typed API for `GetChannelSubscribers()` in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/1476e232502f690ba1832600c221ad76c15cfda7) that's now available from [v4.0.57 on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) which provides a Typed API to fetch all users subscribed to the `ServerEventsClient` channels, e.g:

```
var channelSubscribers = sseClient.GetChannelSubscribers();
```

Comment: Are there equivalent events on the server side, my need is to create a sort of classic TCP/IP type client-server where the server must run background stuff and update the clients (and not be dependent on someone calling omething to start doing that).

Comment: Also on a side note, when a client disconnects uncleanly (say you kill the app) and they don't get a chance to unregister the server doesn't remove them from the active subscribers list (/event-subscribers) for a long time (in the region of minutes).

Comment: @Ravenheart you can register a callback on `ServerEventsFeature.OnUnsubscribe`, it also gets fired when the client doesn't unregister cleanly since they'll stop sending heartbeats and after `ServerEventsFeature.IdleTimeout` (default 30secs) it will automatically be unsubscribed.